# Moving between UIViewControllers without Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a storyboard that has 8 `UIViewController`s on it (and counting). I need to be able to move between any pair of these on demand. Essentially, what I am trying to do is to mimic the functionality of a `UITabBarController`. Since there are so many of these, I can't just use the `UITabBarController` (that would solve my problem immediately), so I am using a `UIPopoverController` with an embedded `UITableView` to allow the user to choose their destination.

Of course, I could create segues on the storyboard, but to set up all of the segues that I need currently, I would have to create 56 such segues just for the view controllers that I have right now, and potentially many more as things grow.

One idea that I had was to create a 'hub' view controller that doesn't really do anything other than to hold the segues to each of the 'real' VCs and be the delegate of each of those VCs. Then, when I want to switch between VCs, I first dismiss the view controller and pass the segue name for the destination back to the hub. The hub can then immediately perform that segue, which gets me where I want. I think that this would work, but is seems sort of hackish.

Does anyone know how if there is a better way to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you give each one a storyboard identifier, then grab anyone you need with its identifier using this:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```

Then present this view controller via push or present modally

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll give it a try and post back with the result.